# Unable to install apk into my work profile

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, intune, intunemam

Unable to install debug apk into work profile. The command i am trying to run is
`adb install --user 12 app-debug.apk`. I have a work profile and when i list the users the id for work profile is 12 .

Is there any permissions i am missing in my intune user account for me to run the adb install app.apk into the work profile account ?

Previously, the way i used to test was

1. Connect the device with usb debugging enabled list devices `adb devices`
2. Login to the company portal account download/install the deployed app (App with intune sdk is deployed to playstore)
3. Run adb install app.apk and it used to overwrite (both contain the same package name). This no longer works (worked 2 days back) and when i try below is the error i get. (I use an Android 13 device)

How do i get my debug apk overwritten into the work profile ? Am i missing some permissions for my work profile user in azure intune?

[image: Updated the correct picture of the error]

Comment: yes it does not work on android13 works on android 11 not sure why